Как сделать, что при уменьшении окна браузера картинки не съехжали?
Подскажите, как сделать, что при уменьшении окна, картинки оставались вместе с текстом, через медиа это писать - запариться можно, потому что писать каждый пиксель не вариант, а съезжают картинки при каждом пикселе все выше и все левее, скрины прикрепил, прошу помочь


HTML
    <div class="glavna">
    <div class="text">
        <a>Быстрые <br>займы на карту</a>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
        <div class="img1">
            <img src="/aaas/Frame 385.png">
        </div>
        <div class="img2">
            <img src="/aaas/Frame 384.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS
.img1 {
    padding-left: 17%;
    padding-top: 2.3%;
}

.img2 {
    padding-left: 3.5%;
    padding-top: 4.5%;
}

Прошу помочь

Воспользуйтесь позиционированием: разместите картинки относительно блока text - тогда они будут оставаться на месте

Пробуй так

.glavna {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
}

.text {
    flex: 1;
}

.img {
    display: flex; 
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.img1, .img2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


В кратце о том, что добавилось:
В твоем контейнере .glavna добавил Flexbox - c помощью него элементы располагаются как бы в строку + адаптируются к размеру экрана;
Свойство flex:1 - элементы занимают все пространство;
Свойство flex-wrap - перенос строк;
Ну и для адаптации изображений свойства max-width:100%, height:auto
